# Appending table row through jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, foreach

I have a piece of HTML table which is returned by the server and it looks like following:

```
     <tbody>
      <tr role="row" class="odd even pointer">
        <td class="" width="5%" tabindex="0">
        <ul class="enlarge">
         <li>
         <img src="" width="60px" height="60px">
            <span>
            <img src="">
            </span>
           </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="sorting_1" width="75%" data-url="" data-title="Sai Baba Nag Champa Incense 250 Gram, New, Free Shipping" data-price="11.25" data-image="" data-itemid="251908749939"> </td>
     <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
       £ 11
       </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

What I'm currently doing is injecting the entire HTML in my DOM right away... But instead of doing it like this:

```
 var dbtb = $('#datatable-responsive', data).html();
 console.log(dbtb);
 $('#datatable-responsive').html(dbtb
```

I would like to first fetch all the TR's from the table, and then append them directly into the table itself in DOM, but through a for/foreach loop?

How could I achieve this?

Comment: P.S. guys, there are many TR's in this table body, so I'd just like to fetch each and every one of them and then append them in my DOM ?

Comment: I didn't get what you're trying to do. You already have an HTML table and you want to get all the rows and then append them where? The DOM is the entire HTML page, where in the DOM do you want to append them? Since they are table rows, they can only be appropriately appended to a table, so are you trying to copy them from one table to another?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. My best guess is you are trying to copy those rows to another table. If that's the case it should be as simple as:

```
$('table tr').appendTo('#target');
```

assuming that `<table id="target">` is the target one